Unable to create and access a json array

Above is the code I have written to create an access a JSON array, however, when I run the console.log() command I get the following error:


Don't post pictures of text. Post the text, and mark it up with code fences or indent it with four spaces. Also, plenty of debugging you can do here yourself before needing SO: even just console log that myObj to spot the mistake you made all on your own.

Does this answer your question? How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?

You have a json object that contains a field with key employees and value list of employees, to get the first employee you should access the list using the employees key, after accessing the value you can call the first item 0
You should access employees first
const my_json = 'myjson'
const my_data = JSON.parse(my_json)
const employees = my_data.employees 
const myobj = employees[0].firstName

